# getUserMedia results in TrackStartError in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I had a WebRTC application that was previously working and now I get the error `TrackStartError` while calling `getuserMedia()`.

I'm using Chrome version 50.0.2661.75 m (64-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Google discontinued the usage of the following audio constraints: `googEchoCancellation2`, `googAutoGainControl`, `googAutoGainControl2`, `googNoiseSuppression2`. Removing these constraints worked for me. `googAutoGainControl` could be the one mostly used.

Comment: in what chrome version? There have been some constraint changes recently, in particular https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4906#c14
I think those constraints are obsolete these days but things should not break without proper announcement.

Comment: I updated my question with the Chrome version. I agree with you, but it happened and I thought I share so others may benefit and not lose time trying to figure out.

Comment: Those should have always been optional constraints, I mean, I assume only Chromium based browsers supported them anyway. They were prefixed for a reason (to denote them as experimental and breakable at any point). Did you define them as mandatory constraints? If so, while a small announcement would have been nice, your code was wrong anyway...

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4906#c16 -- quite likely this change was covered by the "PSA: stuff is going to break".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, i was using this flags

```js
"mandatory": {
    googTypingNoiseDetection: false,
    googEchoCancellation: false,
    googEchoCancellation2: false,
    googAutoGainControl: false,
    googAutoGainControl2: false,
    googNoiseSuppression: false,
    googNoiseSuppression2: false,
    googHighpassFilter: false,
}
```

now, I have to verify if chrome version is higher than 50, in that case only uses these flags

```js
"mandatory": {
    googTypingNoiseDetection: false,
    googEchoCancellation: false,
    //googEchoCancellation2: false,
    googAutoGainControl: false,
    //googAutoGainControl2: false,
    googNoiseSuppression: false,
    //googNoiseSuppression2: false,
    googHighpassFilter: false,
}
```

Comment: communication.js:180 An error occurred: [CODE OverconstrainedError] What about this...

Answer (score 1):

goog prefixed constraints are used on your own risk and they can stop working at any time. The proper way to disable audio processing in Chrome is to set echoCancellation to false.

Comment: echoCancellation does not disable all the audio filters in Chrome.

Comment: It turns off the APM module in WebRTC. Not sure what you been by audio filters in Chrome.