# NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

I get this error in Firefox 51 when I try to execute the following code and when I select my laptop's camera:

```
navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
  },
  function(stream) {
    if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
      video.mozSrcObject = stream;
    } else {
      var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }
    video.play();
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log("An error occured! " + err);
  }
);
```

Error:

```
NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource
```

Can someone elaborate what this means? Is my webcam broken? I used it from the script just yesterday without problems. It's not allocated to other application.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'getUserMedia' called on an object that does not implement interface MediaDevices.` because [your polyfill is borked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37687846/918910). Also, your [browser-conditional code is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39136641/918910), and `createObjectURL` [is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40210033/918910). Consider [using adapter.js instead](http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/srn9db4h/), or enjoy that most browsers now already support `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` natively.

Comment: Also if you could please let me know which example code or article inspired your code here, so I can hunt it down and burn it I would appreciate it. ;)

Comment: Firefox warned me about the polyfill and suggested `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, which actually didn't work and threw an error. I don't know where did I copy that from. If I were to judge it, the main problem I see is that it uses `<video>` tag to capture frames, rather than some programming API. I'll check the links you gave me in order to make the example more up to date, but I think we can agree it's not the cause of the problem. Thanks for the feedback and the warnings.

Comment: Agree, but without seeing the real code and knowing the real circumstances, it's hard to know what's going wrong. This [wfm](http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/srn9db4h/) fwiw (uses a video tag, just like your example).

Comment: If you still see "NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource" by the time you closed all the browser tabs, other browsers and applications, try restarting your computer.

Comment: If you are in window 10 change your microphone and camera app settings

Comment: [Error solved!! DOM Exception Could not start video source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924370/14144530)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`NotReadableError` is the spec compliant error thrown by Firefox when webcam access is allowed but not possible.

**Most commonly this happens on Windows because the webcam is already in use by another app.** Firefox will throw this error on both Windows and Mac even though only on Windows processes get exclusive access to the webcam.

The error can happen for other reasons:

> Although the user granted permission to use the matching devices, a hardware error occurred at the operating system, browser, or Web page level which prevented access to the device.

Chrome throws `TrackStartError` instead. It also throws it for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695834/getusermedia-results-in-trackstarterror-in-chrome/36695835) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481163/webrtc-issue-in-chrome-59). Chrome tabs can share the same device.

Source:  [common getUserMedia() errors](https://blog.addpipe.com//common-getusermedia-errors/) .

Comment: What is the possible solution(s) to it? when no other app is/was using webcam, still getting this error?

Comment: @smkrn110 maybe you had this problem also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568498/notreadableerror-failed-to-allocate-videosource/57101357#57101357

Answer (score 16):

Please make sure your camera is not been used by some other application (chrome, ie or any other browser).
I wasted half my day searching for a solution, and in the end, found out my camera was used by other application.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered same issue on Windows 10, no other apps using my video device. The problem was that in Windows 10 in Settings->App permissions (in left column) there is a setting for microphone and camera (Allow apps to access your mic/camera) which needs to be turned on. It does not matter that you don't find your browser in app list below this setting, just enable it here and voila.

Comment: In my case, camera permission was there but microphone wasn't. So, after giving microphone permission it was all OK.

Answer (score 2):

The message `getUserMedia() error: NotReadableError` was displayed for Chromium but not Firefox web browser. I also noticed that WebRTC examples using `getUserMedia` function without microphone access worked correctly in Chromium.

In fact, I had to make sure my microphone is enabled and select the correct microphone in Chromium / Chrome settings. Then WebRTC with audio and video access worked correctly.

If it is not a microphone problem, it may also be a webcam problem so you have to make sure your webcam is enabled and selected correctly in Chromium / Chrome settings.

Note that only one app at a time can use the webcam / microphone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are here after or in December 2019 i would like to tell you few things

1. This feature `navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated.
2. Successor of this feature in the browsers will be `window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.
3. The new feature may not support in many browsers, since its still in the experiment mode few days ago chrome released its chrome 79 and its still not supporting in chrome 79 for me, and other than chrome and IE its working in all the browsers for me
4. Here is a quick code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Jello</title>
    <style>
        video{
            width: 30%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay controls></video>
    <button>Open Cam</button>
    <script>
    function getCam(){
        window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then((stream)=>{
            // let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            // console.log(videoTrack);
            document.querySelector("video").srcObject = stream;
        }).catch(err=> console.log(err.name))
    }
    // getCam();
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", getCam);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit => **if you are using in windows 10 make sure give chrome access your microphone and camera, otherwise it won't work**

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution to this problem. I had it with camera not working in Firefox and Skype, but working with the Camera app.

The solution was to give access to camera for "classical apps" (I do not know how it's called in English). It is in the same place access can be given or taken for all other apps, just bellow them make sure the classical apps are allowed as well. And not just giving for the app in question, like Firefox, all classical apps need to have that enabled

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr; - Check device drivers for any "funny" camera drivers

I just spent an hour on a call with a user who kept hitting this error, no matter what we tried and that includes go down every answer to this question. And we found another cause which I will now add here for the next poor soul to stumble on this.

In his case, he had installed an app called ChromaCam (which I exited almost as a first diag step) and this app installs a device driver called "Personify Virtual Camera Universal" Web search for that driver name will show a whole bunch of people having camera problems and the solution seems to be somewhat universal: uninstall the device driver.  He didn't even know what ChromaCam was or why it was on his laptop, so we removed it, uninstalled the driver and everything started working perfectly!

There was another person in a different thread who had similar problem and for him it was some custom HP (?? - I think that's what he said) camera driver instead of normal generic one that Windows would have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone elaborate what this means? Is my webcam broken? I used it
>   from the script just yesterday without problems. It's not allocated to
>   other application.

I've encountered exactly the same issue!

Shame on me! Because, in the meantime I'd added a [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event, including the `event.preventDefault` as reported in the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Example).

After removing this `event.preventDefault`, everything worked fine - as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched everywhere for the solution at last found this. Basically in my case camera permission was turned on and Mozilla firefox can access web cam but chrome can't. Infact older versions of chrome like 74.x can use webcam but latest 84.x cannot. I thought the problem is with chrome but at last, I tried turning on my microphone access from windows 10 settings. Now chrome can access webcam too.

**Solution: Please check you camera and microphone access both are turned on from windows settings.**

Answer (score 0):

The NonReadableError: Could not start video source is also thrown during a session (not local only!) if the camera change happens too quickly.

I don't know the solution yet, but I will edit my post accordingly once I got it.