# WebRTC issue in chrome 59

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

After updating chrome to version 59 the `getUserMedia` for screen sharing is fail with "`NavigatorUserMediaError TrackStartError`". This error happen only if two monitors attached to my laptop, if i using laptop screen only, the WebRTC screen sharing works and `getUserMedia` returns stream as well (This is regrassion from chrome 58).
The mediaConstraints for getUserMedia is

```
{
audio: false,
video: {
  mandatory: {
    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
    chromeMediaSourceId: 'the id returned by chrome.desktopCapture (extension)',
    maxFrameRate: 5
    }
}}
```

You can reproduce this issue [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/). 
Is anybody get this error after updating to chrome 59? 
How can i fix it? Or need to wait for google team fix?

Comment: If the bug is not reported on https://crbug.com then you'd better report it yourself.

Comment: Try to open an issue on [this tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: done: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=732224