# Error: navigator.getUserMedia error:NotReadableError: Could not start video source

Tags: javascript, django, html, html5-video

I am trying to record a video in the web browser with an Android smartphone.

I managed to get the code to work on the web browser in the local server but I am unsure why it isn't working when I access it from a smartphone.

When accessing the page from my Android phone, I get the following error:
navigator.getUserMedia
error:NotReadableError: Could not start
video source

Following is my code:

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription %}{% endblock %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fullwidth">

<div class="select">
    <label for="audioSource">Audio source: </label><select id="audioSource"></select>
</div>
<div class="select">
    <label for="videoSource">Video source: </label><select id="videoSource"></select>
</div>

<video id="gum" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
<video id="recorded" playsinline loop></video>

<div>
    <button id="start">Start camera</button>
    <button id="record" disabled>Start Recording</button>
    <button id="play" disabled>Play</button>
    <button id="download" disabled>Download</button>
</div>

<div>
    <h4>Media Stream Constraints options</h4>
    <p>Echo cancellation: <input type="checkbox" id="echoCancellation"></p>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="errorMsg"></span>
</div>

</div>


<script>
'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */
var audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
    for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
        if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
                'microphone ' + (audioSelect.length + 1);
            audioSelect.appendChild(option);
        } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' +
                (videoSelect.length + 1);
            videoSelect.appendChild(option);
        } else {
            console.log('Found one other kind of source/device: ', deviceInfo);
        }
    }
}
function getStream() {
    if (window.stream) {
        window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.stop();
        });
    }

    var constraints = {
        audio: {
            deviceId: {exact: audioSelect.value}
        },
        video: {
            deviceId: {exact: videoSelect.value}
        }
    };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
        then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
    recordedVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
            .then(gotDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;
let sourceBuffer;

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recordButton.textContent === 'Start Recording') {
    startRecording();
  } else {
    stopRecording();
    recordButton.textContent = 'Start Recording';
    playButton.disabled = false;
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  }
});

const playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  recordedVideo.src = null;
  recordedVideo.srcObject = null;
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  recordedVideo.play();
});

const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
});

function handleSourceOpen(event) {
  console.log('MediaSource opened');
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');
  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
  if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
    console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
    options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
      console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
      errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
      options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
      if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
        options = {mimeType: ''};
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
  };
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
}

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  recordButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream:', stream);
  window.stream = stream;

  const gumVideo = document.querySelector('video#gum');
  gumVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

async function init(constraints) {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    handleSuccess(stream);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
  }
}

document.querySelector('button#start').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const hasEchoCancellation = document.querySelector('#echoCancellation').checked;
  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: {exact: hasEchoCancellation}
    },
    video: {
      width: 1280, height: 720
    }
  };
  console.log('Using media constraints:', constraints);
  await init(constraints);
}); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem? @moonfairy

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ seems appropriate. Did you get this working @moonfairy?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568498/notreadableerror-failed-to-allocate-videosource

Comment: @Maverick omg, that's some good comic. And yes, I am stuck with the same issue now.